# NetBeans 6.9.1 demo (ScrumToys) - JSF 2.0 not rendered in Internet-explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, netbeans, internet-explorer-8, jsf-2

In ScrumToys web-application (NetBeans JSF 2.0 demo) the .jsf page is not renderend in internet-explorer (I see the page source as XML).
This works fine in 'proper' browsers, like Chrome and FireFox.

I'm using the [ScrumToys](http://netbeans.org/kb/samples/scrum-toys.html) demo app provided by NetBeans 6.9.1 (running on GlassFish 3) with absolutely no changes. I'm using Internet-explorer 8, accessing this url:
`http://localhost:8080/scrumtoys/home.jsf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Netbeans and I am not going to download it to check the one and other, but it's well known that IE has a problem with `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml`. The output will be displayed as plain XML instead of rendered as HTML.

The symptoms which you describe match this issue. In order to fix it, the `Content-Type` of the page has to be `text/html` and the doctype has preferably to be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. If that was indeed the solution, then it honestly said astonishes me that the demo application was shipped like that.

#### See also:

- [Activating browser modes with doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).
- [Is it possible to use JSF/Facelets with HTML4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)

Comment: The problem was a missing Doctype declaration in their template.xhtml file. I'm astonished too. Am I betting on the wrong horse? (NetBeans, GlassFish3, EE 6, JSF 2.0) Should I be using something more stable for my apps? (JBoss? WebLogic? EE 5? Eclipse? JSF 1.2?) I was hoping to avoid the biolerplate code and XML spaghetti related to the older versions.

Comment: Well, the fault is actually in the demo application, not in Netbeans itself. Blame the developers of the demo applications. At its own, GF3, JEE6 and JSF2 are perfectly fine. Netbeans as being an IDE seems to be pretty decent as well. It's just all in the hands of the developer.

Answer (score 1):

A possible 'quick fix' is to add the following to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <description>The default for this parameter is false. Fixes IE xhtml content-type restriction.</description>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.preferXHTML</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```