# How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?

Tags: jsf, xhtml, include, jsf-2, facelets

What is the most correct way to include another XHTML page in an XHTML page? I have been trying different ways, none of them are working.

Answer (score 451, accepted):

### `<ui:include>`

Most basic way is [`<ui:include>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/include.html). The included content must be placed inside [`<ui:composition>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/composition.html).

Kickoff example of the master page `/page.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Include demo</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Master page</h1>
        <p>Master page blah blah lorem ipsum</p>
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/include.xhtml" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The include page `/WEB-INF/include.xhtml` (yes, this is the file in its entirety, any tags outside `<ui:composition>` are unnecessary as they are ignored by Facelets anyway):

```
<ui:composition 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h2>Include page</h2>
    <p>Include page blah blah lorem ipsum</p>
</ui:composition>
```

This needs to be opened by `/page.xhtml`. Do note that you don't need to repeat `<html>`, `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` inside the include file as that would otherwise result in [invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org).

You can use a dynamic EL expression in `<ui:include src>`. See also [How to ajax-refresh dynamic include content by navigation menu? (JSF SPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108668/how-to-ajax-refresh-dynamic-include-content-by-navigation-menu-jsf-spa).

---

### `<ui:define>`/`<ui:insert>`

A more advanced way of including is *templating*. This includes basically the other way round. The master template page should use [`<ui:insert>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/insert.html) to declare places to insert defined template content. The template client page which is using the master template page should use [`<ui:define>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/define.html) to define the template content which is to be inserted.

Master template page `/WEB-INF/template.xhtml` (as a design hint: the header, menu and footer can in turn even be `<ui:include>` files):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="header">Header</div>
        <div id="menu">Menu</div>
        <div id="content"><ui:insert name="content">Default content</ui:insert></div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Template client page `/page.xhtml` (note the `template` attribute; also here, this is the file in its entirety):

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="title">
        New page title here
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>New content here</h1>
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This needs to be opened by `/page.xhtml`. If there is no `<ui:define>`, then the default content inside `<ui:insert>` will be displayed instead, if any.

---

### `<ui:param>`

You can pass parameters to `<ui:include>` or `<ui:composition template>` by [`<ui:param>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/param.html).

```
<ui:include ...>
    <ui:param name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
</ui:include>
```

```
<ui:composition template="...">
    <ui:param name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    ...
</ui:composition >
```

Inside the include/template file, it'll be available as `#{foo}`. In case you need to pass "many" parameters to `<ui:include>`, then you'd better consider registering the include file as a tagfile, so that you can ultimately use it like so `<my:tagname foo="#{bean.foo}">`. See also [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000)

You can even pass whole beans, methods and parameters via `<ui:param>`. See also [JSF 2: how to pass an action including an argument to be invoked to a Facelets sub view (using ui:include and ui:param)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004233/jsf-2-how-to-pass-an-action-including-an-argument-to-be-invoked-to-a-facelets-s)

---

### Design hints

The files which aren't supposed to be publicly accessible by just entering/guessing its URL, need to be placed in `/WEB-INF` folder, like as the include file and the template file in above example. See also [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811)

There doesn't need to be any markup (HTML code) outside `<ui:composition>` and `<ui:define>`. You can put any, but they will be **ignored** by Facelets. Putting markup in there is only useful for web designers. See also [Is there a way to run a JSF page without building the whole project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504190)

The HTML5 doctype is the recommended doctype these days, "in spite of" that it's a XHTML file. You should see XHTML as a language which allows you to produce HTML output using a XML based tool. See also [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5) and [JavaServer Faces 2.2 and HTML5 support, why is XHTML still being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used).

CSS/JS/image files can be included as dynamically relocatable/localized/versioned resources. See also [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

You can put Facelets files in a reusable JAR file. See also [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486).

For real world examples of advanced Facelets templating, check the `src/main/webapp` folder of [Java EE Kickoff App source code](https://github.com/javaeekickoff/java-ee-kickoff-app) and [OmniFaces showcase site source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/showcase).

Comment: Hi Balus, regarding: Most basic way is <ui:include>. The included content must be placed inside <ui:composition>. I thing the included content can simply be in <p> </p> it will work.

Comment: @KorayTugay: Yes, that's correct. ui:composition is only necessary to a) use a template (see above), or b) to wrap everything in <html><body> so you can load the file with a browser or HTML editor.

Comment: Hi can you please solve this riddle for me? I have been banging my head from past 3 days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738079/dynamic-rendering-of-uiinclude-wont-work-when-uirepeat-is-used-in-included-fa

Comment: Hello, BalusC. In case you are still here: is there way to include other page without wrapping it with <ui:composition>? Just include it literally like old-style C headers =)

Comment: @Odysseus: not if it's actually a composition.

Comment: Great and precise explanation, it explains everything using comparison of 2 approaches

Comment: Afaik if only declaring `<ui:composition ...>` inside facelet you have to declare the doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` also, otherwise you get an `entity referenced but not declared` error when using HTML entities.

Comment: After 3 days this template method not work at all, simple include is ok but templating is complete fail. Coming from asp .net and this jsf is so complicated just to create simple view layouts.

Comment: Is an included ui:composition thingie independent of all other identical included thingies included in the same composite object? My limited understanding of composition says yes, but I have a Facelets page that includes the same Facelets ui:composition snippet twice, each in a separate tab. The snippet contains a datatable that has different content in the two tabs. Both datatables populate normally when first rendered but when I switch from one tab to the other the previously populated datatable is empty and only a page refresh restores it. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 25):

Included page:

```
<!-- opening and closing tags of included page -->
<ui:composition ...>
</ui:composition>
```

Including page:

```
<!--the inclusion line in the including page with the content-->
<ui:include src="yourFile.xhtml"/>
```

- You start your included xhtml file with `ui:composition` as shown above.
- You include that file with `ui:include` in the including xhtml file as also shown above.

Comment: Sometimes it's not enough to identify the path while you use just a file name. For those, who tried the file inclusion above and it didn't work. You can try adding a slash symbol before file name or /WEB-INF directory. So it looks like  `<ui:include src="/yourFile.xhtml"/>` or `<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/yourFile.xhtml"/>`