# How to render XHTML compliant form in JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I'm trying to create a `form` compliant to XHTML 1.1 with JSF, but can't. This is my `.xhtml` file:

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="foo"/>
  <h:commandButton action="search" value="Search" />
</h:form>
```

In the output HTML `<input>` tags are not enclosed in `<div>` or `<dd>` or something similar, as they should be in XHTML 1.1. Is there any legal workaround? I don't like the idea of adding these tags explicitly to `.xhtml` file.

Comment: Which JSF implementation do you actually use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add those [block elements](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) yourself?

```
<h:form>
  <p><h:inputText value="foo"/></p>
  <p><h:commandButton action="search" value="Search" /></p>
</h:form>
```

Note that JSF will never render 100% valid XHTML 1.1. Use XHTML 1.0 Transitional or [HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5).

Comment: Such a pity... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's only a pity for ones who worships w3 and forget that browser hacks are sometimes simply mandatory.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but now I'm getting `<input type="hidden" name="j_idt19" value="j_idt19" />` right after `<form>` element, before my first `<p>`.. Any ideas?

Comment: As said, JSF will never render 100% valid XHTML 1.1. JSF is on paper specified to render XHTML 1.0 Transitional. If you want XHTML 1.1, you need to create/extend/override a custom XHTML 1.1 renderer for components which need it (`HtmlForm` and so on). Or just use a HTML5 doctype. Feeding browsers a `text/html` response with a XHTML doctype makes IMO no sense.