# JSF 2 with HTML pages instead of XHTML

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to get JSF setup to use files with a html extension.

If I use a .xhtml pattern (`<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`) and name my files with a xhtml extension, the pages load correctly and get parsed.

However, if I change this to `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` and naming the files with a .html extension, I get 500 an error:

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Server logs:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:748)
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.isEmpty(ELFlash.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:318)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:208)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1139)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:136)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">   
  <display-name>com.test.cms</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *However, if I change this to *.html **and naming the files with a .html extension**, I get 500 an error*

Did you mean that you renamed the physical `.xhtml` files to `.html`? You should not have the need to do that. Rename them back to `.xhtml` and keep using the `.html` in URLs. The `FacesServlet` will automatically load the right XHTML file associated with the URL.

If you really need to give them the `.html` extension, then you'd need to change the default suffix to `.html` as well. Add the following entry to `web.xml` to achieve that:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.html</param-value>
</context-param>
```

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my problem and thanks for the extra explanations :)

Answer (score 4):

As BalusC said you don't need to change the physical file names.

But anyway I spotted odd values in your web.xml schema. There are mixed version 2_5 and 3_0 values.

With the settings below you should be able to keep files with `.xhtml` extension and access them as `.html`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I tested it in GlassFish 3.1.2 with Mojarra 2.1.6 and it works fine.

I hope it helps.