# IDE creates xhtml instead of .jsf as extension

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jsf-2

I'm so new for JavaServer Faces. I'm trying to create a project in Netbeans. (New Project >Java Web>Web Application). While creating I changed JSF Servlet URL Pattern.

It was like this:

[image: demo]

And I changed it as "*.jsf" then created. Netbeans edited web.xml file.

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

But my index page is still xHTML.

[image: index page]

Lastly, when I run to file, IDE trying to open `index.html` and browser can't find index.HTML so I go index.jsf and page opens.

I've been searching for a while, I just find about people suggests editing to web.xml but its already edited. So do you have any suggestion?

Comment: In your web.xml you have mapped the servlet with url *.jsf, it means that your pages are mapped with that extension. If you only want to access the pages with extension xhtml try to change <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern> in <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>.

Comment: Actually I want to access the pages wtih extension jsf. But someway index.html not turn to index.jsf . and Its kinda problem. Why is still index.html ? Is it supposed to be index.html ?

Comment: If you want that index.html turn to index.jsf you have to add another url-pattern, see the Subodh Joshi [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38355009/6546865) with the links he posted.

Comment: Sorry for that comment. I made a word mistake. I even couldnt xhtml to html. so all I have is xhtml files and its default URL extension

Answer (score 2):

Then you can use below servlet-mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you can use more than one pattern as well please check below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For more and detail information you can check BalusC's evergreen answers for following questions.

- [What is the difference between creating .xhtml or .jsp .or .jsf for JSF pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-xhtml-or-jsp-or-jsf-for-jsf-pages)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [JSF 2 with HTML pages instead of XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828788/jsf-2-with-html-pages-instead-of-xhtml)

For your question why its created `index.html` rather than `index.xhtml` you can check following link

- [Creating a new JSF project](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-create-new-jsf-project)

it will tell you step by step process to create a JSF project and at last it creating `index.xhtml` page rather than `index.html`. So from this link you can get which step you missed in your case.

Please check below two screens

**1. Step 1**

[image]

**2. Step 2**

[image]

You can check highlighted(Yellow Color) text  its extension is `.XHTML` and not `.HTML`

Comment: Well I am sorry for comment up there I made a mistake I was trying to write xhtml but I did html. It should be 
 
----Actually I want to access the pages wtih extension jsf. But someway index.xhtml not turn to index.jsf . and Its kinda problem. Why is still index.xhtml ? Is it supposed to be index.xhtml ? ----

My index page is same as you. Its like picture you post it. But I want it as index.jsf . I am looking sites you post but i still couldnt get my answer  maybe I  miss out something idk :/ let me look it again

Comment: In your servlet mapping use   `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>`  then you can access your page `abc.jsf` no issue if your actual page name is`abc.xhtml` .URL pattern use to call JSF servlet and process the  JSF life cycle .

Comment: Yes I can access. I was thinking  why its still abc.xhtml in netbeans and thinking it must be abc.jsf in netbeans side too. So I guess I  dont have problem I just didnt know its no issue being abc.xhtml I thought its a problem. Thank you for giving me time and sorry for wasting your time :(