# JSF 2.2 <!doctype html> not working

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

I have a jsf `.xhtml` file. If I use the doctype

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

everything works fine. But I'd like to have an HTML5-Site. When I add the

```html
<!doctype html>
```

doctype I receive this error:

```
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
```

Whats the Problem?

Here is my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>ZaplianceLogAnalyser</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: try with DOCTYPE

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If yes, please accept an answer or post your solution to mark the question as closed

Answer (score 0):

Did you put

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

in your web.xml file?

Comment: Yes, here is my Web.xml. Ok it's to long...I'll paste.bin ist

Comment: What type of encoding do you have on this file (html)? Did you try to use DOCTYPE in uppercase as @mr mcwolf suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following changes:

1. Use [`<!DOCTYPE html>`](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_doctype.asp) instead of `<!doctype html>` like **mr mcwolf** suggested
2. Map your JSF pages to [`*.xhtml` instead of `*.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9829006/4906586) unless you're already consistent with that choice but I see that you set your `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` to `.xhtml` and you are using `.xhtml` files... Further [reading about why `.xhtml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19191939/4906586)
3. I'm not sure for web.xml but I now have the habit to use the [`xmlns.jcp.org`](https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/jsf22-namespaces/) namespace everywhere instead of `java.sun.com` including the web.xml header:

   ```xml
   <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1" >
   ```