# <audio> tag in JSF page

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, html5-audio

I want to display an audio file in a JSF file, and this is my code. The problem is that, in my Eclipse editor, it always reminds that "Unknown tag (audio). " with a yellow warning in Eclipse. I test it in the web server, can's see anything related to the audio shown on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<!-- The template for our app, defines some regions -->


<body>

    <div id="container" align="left">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="resources/images/logo.png" alt="logo photo" />
        </div>
        <br />      

        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content" />
        </div>

        <br style="clear: both" />
    </div>
    <audio src="resources/audio/test.wav" /> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As to unknown tag, why are you using XHTML doctype instead of HTML5 doctype? You said yourself, it's a HTML5 element. So you should use a HTML5 doctype instead. As to the attribute, XML doesn't support attribute minimization, just specify an arbitrary value, e.g. `controls="controls"` like you'd do for `checked="checked"`, `selected="selected"`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. But what I really need is to display audio in a JSF file, not really a HTML5 page. I thought JSF is eventually converted into HTML. Right?

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used

Comment: I simplified it to <audio src="resources/audio/Txt2Wav.wav" type="audio/wav" />. The red flag error message is gone in the editor, but still a yellow flag in the editor indicating that it's an "unknown tag".

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: Any clues in browser's web developer toolset? (press F12 in case you didn't know)

Comment: It turns out that HTML5 tag <audio controls="x"><source src="resources/audio/test.wav" type="audio/wav" /> </audio> although it still warns that the tag is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by BalusC, this can be resolved by changing the doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

JSF can work with it.

See also:

- [JavaServer Faces 2.2 and HTML5 support, why is XHTML still being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used)