# Control generated ID of ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat, clientid, passthrough-elements

Sorry for the simple question. I am learning to use JSF 2.2 to create a form and trying to keep it close to plain HTML5 as possible. I have an ui:repeat generated list that goes like this:

```
<ul id="nameLst">
    <ui:repeat var="d" value="#{controller.names}" varStatus="status">
        <li>
            <input
                jsf:id="nameTxt"
                jsf:binding="#{nameTxt}"
                jsf:value="#{d}"
                type="hidden" />#{d}
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

It gets rendered like this:

```
<ul id="nameLst">
    <li>
        <input id="j_idt14:0:nameTxt" name="j_idt14:0:nameTxt" value="Name1" type="hidden">
        Name1
    </li>
    <li>
        <input id="j_idt14:1:nameTxt" name="j_idt14:1:nameTxt" value="Name2" type="hidden">
        Name2
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I am trying to add names using JavaScript only to this list. Problem is, how can I control this generated id, so I can use it in JavaScript. And mainly, if the list starts empty, how do I generate this id so it can be correctly posted back to the managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

> *how can I control this generated id, so I can use it in JavaScript*

Just give it a fixed `id`.

```
<ui:repeat id="names" ...>
```

Alternatively, use `jsfc` attribute to turn `<ul>` into an `<ui:repeat>`.

```
<ul id="names" jsfc="ui:repeat" value="#{bean.names}" var="name">
    <li>
        <input jsf:id="name" type="hidden" value="#{name}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

> *And mainly, if the list starts empty, how do I generate this id so it can be correctly posted back to the managed bean*

Use JSF for this instead of JS. An example can be found here: [How to dynamically add JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409053/how-to-dynamically-add-jsf-components)

#### See also:

- [How can I know the id of a JSF component so I can use in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045307/how-can-i-know-the-id-of-a-jsf-component-so-i-can-use-in-javascript)
- [JavaServer Faces 2.2 and HTML5 support, why is XHTML still being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189372/javaserver-faces-2-2-and-html5-support-why-is-xhtml-still-being-used)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the help. About the part where the list might start empty, you suggested to use JSF, but when doing so, for the list to be updated I would have to call the backing bean every time. I would really like to edit the list and only post when the user is done adding and removing items. Since I now have the id, I can create li entries exactly like the the ones generated by the ui:repeat using JS, but the new entries don't seem to be posted to backing bean. Should they, or is there any issue other than creating ids with nameList:0:name, nameList:1:name and so on.

Comment: For exactly that reason you need to do it via JSF. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421839