# JSF page not displaying when run

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

By checking web tutorials I am trying to create a demo JSF page. When I try to run it, the page shows blank. Even text without tags are not shown.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:outputLabel  value="#{welcome.welcome()}"/>
</h:body>
```

welcome.java:

```
package ap.demojsf.welcome;

import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.ManagedObject;

@ManagedObject()
@RequestScoped
public class welcome {

private String name;

public welcome() {
    this.name = "Welcome to the first page";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
 }
```

If I write some simple text(without any tags) then I could see when I open index.html in a browser however nothing is displayed when I run it as "Run as". I have Apache Tomcat 7 installed.

Can anyone guide me with it?

Comment: There seems to be an extra backslash in your `html` tag. You should close it too.

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to "Run as..." directly the html/jsp page?

Comment: Sry, thats just my typo while copying the code here. I have updated it.

Comment: Yes, directly run as.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this text not appear in JSF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515438/why-does-this-text-not-appear-in-jsf)

Comment: By the way, `<h:outputLabel>` is the wrong tag for the purpose. Use `<h:outputText>` (after you have fixed the rendering problem, of course). Which tutorial was you reading, by the way? Then I can contact and inform its author about the utterly wrong appliance of `<h:outputLabel>`. I'm seeing this lately really more and more often.

Comment: Its just a youtube tutorial. You can get it here. watch?v=ia0oqx93slk

Comment: Get an authoritative book. Start at our JSF wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info I also strongly recommend to learn basic Servlets beforehand as you seem to fail on grasping that important basic concept on which the whole JSF thing is based. Not understanding basic Servlets makes JSF so much harder to understand.

Comment: Okay Thank you for putting so much effort to guide me. I will give you thumbs up for this :) But you could not have deleted the reply in another question, as it had many useful links given in your reply. Anyways, Thanks BalusC!!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your web.xml if you index.html is your welcome page,  make sure you put **index.html  at the first** and **add *.html* url- pattern as show below** !!

By default tomcat  recognized url in .faces

```
  http://localhost:8080/YourProject/index.xhtml
```

The url above will not work unless you add the pattern .xhtml

```
 http://localhost:8080/YourProject/index.faces
```

This one does!!

```
  <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

You should replace @ManagedObject by @ManagedBean

Comment: Where should I add <welcome-file-list>? In the starting of the web.xml?

Comment: I think there is no order, so i will say anywhere inside the <web-app></web-app> !! Do not forget to restart your server before testing

Comment: Tried it buddy. But no good. It just says 404 error. However server otherwise is working fine.

Comment: Hi, i think i get it, if you try to access the page with index.faces in your browser it will work, it dues to the url-pattern. You can add the pattern you will use as show above !! Hope it's helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputLabel  value="#{welcome.name}"/>
</h:body>
```

Comment: tried it. The thing is even if am not using this approach. If I try <h:head> hello </h:head> then also its not displayed. Code seems to be fine only. The problem is with why result is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Replace `html` tag with `f:view`. BTW, Don't forget to check the proxy setting of your browser.