# Newline in <p:confirm message>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, newline, confirm

Is there a way to put a new line in the message of `<p:confirm>` component?

```
<p:confirm header="Confirmation"  
    message="Are you sure you want to continue? Bla bla bla" 
    icon="ui-icon-alert"  />
```

I would like to have "Bla bla bla" in a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time I asked this question there was no escape option in `confirm` component but it was implemented on PrimeFaces 6.2 after this [feature request](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/60).

So now we can just do it this way:

```
<p:confirm header="Confirmation"  
    escape="false"
    message="Are you sure you want to continue? &lt;br/&gt; Bla bla bla" 
    icon="ui-icon-alert"  />
```

Alternatively, it's possible to use `confirmDialog` component as already suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Message is HTML part, so you need to add `<br>`. Either take message from bean (to prevent xml tag escaping) or use facet:

```
<p:confirmDialog header="Confirmation">
    <f:facet name="message">
        Are you sure you want to continue?<br/>Yes or no?
    </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using a global `confirmDialog`, is there any way I could do this line break inside the `p:confirm` component? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried? This snippet throws `FaceletException` because it's invalid XML.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, I was using <br/> but I've wanted to use valid HTML here. Funny, that the most correct syntax is not accepted :(

Comment: Uh, HTML4 is indeed not valid XML, no, that's also exactly why XHTML and HTML5 exist. How could you miss that fact as "web devie" and particularly JSF developer? See also among others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5/3869174#3869174 and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info

Comment: what we do if we need multiple confirm box at the same page?

Answer (score 2):

There's no "escape" attribute in `p:confirm`, so you may try this.
(Which is work when I tried it.)

Page:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show the Dialog" 
                 onclick="#{MyBean.setMsg('Are you sure you want to continue? &lt;br/&gt; Bla bla bla')}" 
                 oncomplete="conf.show()" update="confDlg">
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog id="confDlg" severity="alert" header="Confirmation" widgetVar="conf" global="true">   
    <f:facet name="message">
       <h:outputText value="#{MyBean.msg}" escape="false"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Backing Bean:(simply getter and setter)

```
   private String msg;

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public String getMsg() {       
    return msg;
}
```

In this way, you can also take advantage of global `confirmDialog`.

However, you may need to edit other commandButtons that show `confirmDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

very easy you can use facet

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="cd" header="Confirm">
     <f:facet name="message">
        <h:outputText value="Are you sure?" />
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="After line break" />
     </f:facet>
    ...
 </p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Why are you repeating an already given answer? This is a Q&A site, not an old fashioned discussion forum.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
<p:confirm header="Confirm title" icon="ui-icon-help" message="This Line\n Next Line" />
```

and style:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" style="white-space: pre;">
...
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have many different messages to show, then I put it into List and do something like that in page:

```
<p:confirmDialog>
  <f:facet name="message">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item">
      <p:panel>
        <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
      </p:panel>
    </ui:repeat>
  </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```