# JSF: Line break with language bundle not possible with \n or <br/>

Tags: java, jsf, line-breaks

i got a language bundle and i want to throw an information message if saving is succesfull. In the facelet i get the message like this:

```
<h:messages infoClass="info" errorClass="error" escape="false" />
```

And in the Backing Bean i wrote it like that:

```
 fcxt.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, rb.getString("save_success"), null));
```

The language pattern for "save_success" is as following:

`Saving successful! <br />You will receive your changes per email and also can have a look at this at your profile.`

I also tried:

`Saving successful! <br />You will receive your changes per email and also can have a look at this at your profile.`

Did anyone know why there is no line break? And how i can get a line break?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `escape` attribute in `h:messages`, so you may try using `h:outputText` like:

```
<h:outputText value="#{MyBean.errMsg}" escape="false"/>
```

And try

> Saving successful! `&lt;br/&gt;` You will receive your changes per email
>   and also can have a look at this at your profile.

For the language pattern. Where `&lt;` stands for `<` and `&gt;` stands for `>`.

Also, you may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365674/newline-in-pconfirm-message/20390015#20390015) to see the code example.