# Primefaces confirmDialog with line break and XSS fears

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a command button with a confirm action using primefaces:

```
<p:commandButton value="Test"
    rendered="..."
    action="#{controller.actionMethod(param)}">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" escape="false" message="This is a really long message test &lt;br/&gt; 
        This is a really long message test."/>
</p:commandButton>
```

I've read that turning off escape is a potential XSS attack vulnerability, so I am trying to fix this issue without the use of a line break in the message (and allow for escape=true)

The confirmDialog is global:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes"
        type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No"
        type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

I've tried using styling using pre-line wrapping, but I haven't had luck. Am I chasing a non-issue? Is this actually an XSS vulnerability?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Newline in <p:confirm message>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365674/newline-in-pconfirm-message)

Comment: Along with @JasperdeVries answer using escape="false" is OK as long as you KNOW the content of what will be put in that box.  If it was user entered data you would never want to use escape="false" but if you are always the author of the content it is OK and exactly what escape="false" is for.

Comment: @Melloware - These dialogs are completely controlled by the developer, nothing that is inputted.

Comment: Then have no fear using escape="false".

Answer (score 2):

A better way to introduce line break in the message would be to use facet as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365674/newline-in-pconfirm-message). This way you get all out of this XSS fuss.

```
<p:confirmDialog header="Confirmation">
    <f:facet name="message">
        Are you sure you want to continue?<br/>Yes or no?
    </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Still if you want to go this way, assuming you are using Prime Faces 7 in the [documentation manual](https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/) several times escape attribute is given without any warning for XSS. I would worry more about XSS when I am getting text input from the user than button input.

Comment: XSS is dangerous when using input from 'untrusted sources' in an unescaped output.So in both your approach (= from a duplicate Q) there is as litlle risk as in the code in the Q

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, it only applies to button input. Had the input been "text input" I agree with you.