# How to use HTML5 Tags within ADF FACES

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, drag-and-drop, oracle-adf

I'am looking for a pretty and easy way to use HTML5 Tags inside of my Adf Faces Application.

I'am using ADF 12c and it's supposed to support HTML5 and CSS3.
Until now i get this

```
   <f:facet name="center">
         <af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it1" placeholder="Test"/>
    </f:facet>
```

placeholder is an HTML5 feature. 
My questions: 
How can i use something as `Canvas` or `Drag and Drop Events`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use canvas tags directly, you can use normal HTML tags with ADF Faces 12c, and you can inject EL anywhere.

check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5) and this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipob.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an HTML5 tag that doesn't have an equivalent in ADF Faces you can use an f:verbatim tag in your JSF and include the HTML code inside it.