# How Oracle ADF Faces renders HTML5 elements

Tags: html, jsf, oracle-adf

I found somewhere on the web the document below. Could somebody help me to find how Oracle ADF Faces renders HTML5 elements?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. ADF Faces components generate markup at runtime and some of those markup components use HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

note that using ADF Faces you wont be exposed to HTML 5 directly.

Instead the ADF Faces components would use HTML 5 in their rendering.

for example if you need a component with the canvas behavior then this need to be provided as an ADF Faces component.

please check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21478272/957654)

Hope that helps .