# javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /template.xhtml: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, doctype, html-entities

In my Facelets template I used a XHTML doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I'd like to change this to [HTML5 doctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5) as per the general recommendation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

However, JSF threw a parsing error:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /template.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.

The HTML `&nbsp;` entity is not parsed then. The entity is used as follows:

```
<p:menuitem value="&nbsp;My menuitem">
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTML5 doctype has no predefined entities. It assumes that the entire document is already UTF-8 aware. In other words, you can "safely" put the real non breaking space character in the HTML5 document. However, as it's not trivial to enter it in a visible way using a regular US keyboard, it's understandable that many developers prefer using an entity for it.

Facelets in turn supports as being a XML based view technology only [five predefined XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`. The `&nbsp;` is not among them.

You've 2 options (apart from the 3rd option to just print the character straight in the document):

1. Declare the `&nbsp;` entity yourself in the doctype:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html [
       <!ENTITY nbsp "&#xA0;"> 
   ]>
   ```
2. Or, use the (hexa)decimal notation instead:

   ```
   &#xA0; or &#160;
   ```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your answer. I've tried the 1st option and it has functioned.