# How to use JSF Expression Language in predesigned plain HTML page

Tags: html, jsf, el

JSF uses its own tags generally in XHTML page (ex : `h:inputText` etc). But suppose that we have an already designed plain HTML page and we want to use JSF Expression Language (EL) on it. How to achieve it?

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="textField" type= "text" class="form-control" name="searchingWord" placeholder="Search Something ..." value="#{wordController.searchingWord}"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn"> <a id="searchButton" class="btn btn-danger" href="search.html"> SEARCH </a> </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to turn a plain HTML element into a JSF component is to replace `id` by `jsf:id`.

```
<... xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
...
<form jsf:id="form">
    ...
    <input jsf:id="textField" ... />
    ...
</form>
```

Rest is automatic if you map the `FacesServlet` on the URL-pattern matching the HTML pages (e.g. `*.html`). This JSF 2.2+ feature is called "[passthrough elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm)".

#### See also:

- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5/)