# JSF: Is it possible to use .HTML instead of .XHTML?

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

When you are developing a JavaServer Faces application, are you bound to develop a web page in XHTML or is it possible to use HTML instead?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
```

The reason why I prefer to develop in HMTL is first and foremost that I am more used to it. And it's easier to implement add-ons like Bootstrap (at least when you are not used to XHTML). If it's possible to use HTML instead, how do I configure the tags get the same result if I used to default setup?

Comment: The difference between the two is 'minimal'. Click on the tags and read it. I use all normal 'html' things in my xhtml files. Regardless of using things like boostrap or not. If it is just about the extension (which I assume it is not), then thats what it is, configuring an extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)