# Turn on warnings for unclosed tags in facelets with Eclipse and HTML5 doctype

Tags: html, eclipse, jsf-2, syntax-highlighting, facelets

I am trying to use HTML5 in my JSF project using Facelets. I know, per this @BalusC answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869174/9195115, that that is possible. However, with the HTML5 doctype, Eclipse doesn't show any warnings for unclosed tags, such as `link` or `meta`.

For example, in the following facelet, I would like Eclipse to show a warning/error, because, although it is valid HTML5, it is not valid XML, which results in `javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /new.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 7] The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".` I am using WildFly 11 with JSF 2.2 and Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:head>
    <title>New page</title>
    <link href="style.css"><!-- Warning here -->
  </h:head>
  <body>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </body> 
</html>
```

I already spent a lot of time in Eclipse preferences trying to find an option to do this. Is there any option to turn on these warnings that I missed, or is there any plugin that will do this?

Comment: You might need to file a bug report.

Comment: Off-topic: for jsf 2.2 you can (should) use newer namespaces. And can't you just configure this in the validators? What is your eclipse version?

Comment: Edited the post to add the Eclipse version.

Comment: Did you check to turn on xhtml validation when an html doctype is encounterd in the validators in Eclipse? Mars and Oxygen2 have these options!

Comment: That sounds exactly what I need. Where can I turn that on? I don't find anything about the html doctype in the xhtml syntax validator.