# Javascript working in HTML but not XHTML JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

I am working on a web-app that is using **JSF 2.1** and **RichFaces 3.3**

I have an external piece of Javascript that needs to run across all of the applications' pages, so I put it in the head of my template file, call it `layout.xhtml`, 

This is used as the template by all of the different pages, so I think I've put it in the right place at least.
 `<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">`
The script itself is okay, tested it on JSFiddle and it runs as expected.

Its format is like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js" 
        data-document-language="true" 
        type="text/javascript" 
        charset="UTF-8" 
        data-domain-script="dummy-value-for-stack-overflow">
</script>
```

When testing within the applcation, I was able to get the script to run fine on a normal `.html` page, however when I change to using a `.xhtml` page I am getting an error in the browser's console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.Groups.forEach is not a function
    at Ct.setPublicDomainData (otBannerSdk.js:7)
    at Ct.<anonymous> (otBannerSdk.js:7)
    at otBannerSdk.js:7
    at Object.next (otBannerSdk.js:7)
    at otBannerSdk.js:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at c (otBannerSdk.js:7)
    at Ct.initializeBannerVariables (otBannerSdk.js:7)
    at otBannerSdk.js:7
    at otBannerSdk.js:7
```

I think this is due to the data attributes in the script tag,
`data-document-language` and `data-domain-script`, as they aren't valid attributes in any of the namespaces I'm using and XHTML is strict about that sort of thing:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    lang="en-US">
```

What I'm thinking is that XHTML doesn't like those data attributes, so the script is trying to run without them, and the console error is arising from a null value.

Is there any way around this? I know that JSF 2.2+ allow for some custom attribute options but I wasn't sure they applied to `script` tags specifically

It's my first time working on a JSF project so apologies if I've missed anything, thanks.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5/ first... I even think it is a duplicate. If it was a server side namespace issue, the server would have complained, not an error in the client. I rather think it is a basic conflict between duplicate .js files being loaded. What is relevant is what the client-side html looks like, not what it server side is and what the client-side error is. Try removing the xmlht namespace like in the duplicate

Comment: You say duplicate .js files being loaded, however in the network tab of the browser, I don't see any duplicates, just a normal GET request with a Status 200 response

Comment: there must be multple get requests since you use richfaces which also uses java. But I mentioned more... Check differences, make a plain xhtml file without richfaces components. Stll errors? Make a [mcve] then... And post the error in a searchengine and investigate... There are things about object vs array etc..

Comment: java should have been javascript in my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, a conflict of some sort occurred as RichFaces was injecting a number of scripts into the `head` portion of the html file, and seemed to cause some strange behaviour with the script I was trying to add.

A workaround was to make a small change to my `web.xml`, changing the RichFaces `LoadScriptStrategy` value from `ALL` to `DEFAULT`

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

`NONE` also worked for me but is advised to be avoided as per their documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#ScriptsandStylesLoadStrategy (getting rid of all of these scripts will probably cause something else to break)

Credit to @Kukeltje for his comments trying to clarify my problem - without that I wouldn't even have considered that RichFaces was the culprit, I was convinced it was an issue with xhtml and tags (it wasn't)

Comment: See why creating a [mcve] is always relevant... Always... it helps a lot in finding root causes or at least narrowing things down tremendously... Always try to create one...