# DOM doesn't find the element in xhtml document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm creating a smooth scrolling in a dialog with Primefaces and jQuery. My idea is: every time that I click on the button 'Comentar', my code needs to scroll the screen at the textArea, at the final of the dialog.

But I have a problem: when I click on the button, my code doesn't find the elementId that he needs to scroll, so it doesn't make the smooth scrolling.

I tested my code, and the parameter 'elementId' is undefined, and I don't know how to resolve this problem.

My code is it:

jQuery:

```
function dialogScroll(dialogId, elementId) {
    console.log("dialogId: " + dialogId)
    console.log("elementId: " + elementId)

    let dlg = $(dialogId);
    let elm = $(elementId);

    if (elm.length) {
        console.log("entrou")
        dlg.find('.ui-dialog-content')
            .first()
            .animate({
                scrollTop: elm.offset().top
            }, 'smooth');
    } else {
        alert($(elementId).offset());
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```html
<p:dialog header="Visualizar anúncio" class="modalAnuncio" id="modalAnuncio" widgetVar="dlgVisualizarAnuncio" modal="true" draggable="true" responsive="true" resizable="false" closeOnEscape="true" closable="true" height="600px" width="634px">
  <h:form id="dialogForm">
    [...]
    <h:panelGroup id="visualizarAvaliacoes">
      [...]
      <h:panelGroup id="container-botao-cadastrar-avaliacao" rendered="#{marketplaceMB.avaliacao eq null}">
        <span class="container-botao-cadastrar-avaliacao">
        <p:commandLink class="botao-cadastrar-avaliacao" id="botao-cadastrar-avaliacao"
                       actionListener="#{marketplaceMB.novaAvaliacao}"
                       process="@this" update="@form:visualizarAvaliacoes"
                       oncomplete="carregarMascaras(); dialogScroll('modalAnuncio', 'dialogForm:panelDialog')"
        >
            <i class="btn-text-cadastro-avaliacao">Comentar</i>
        </p:commandLink>
    </span>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:panelGroup id="pnlCadastrarAvaliacao" rendered="#{marketplaceMB.avaliacao ne null}">
        <p:outputPanel id="panelDialog">
          <div class="container-cadastro-avaliacao" id="container-cadastro-avaliacao">
            <div class="container-campo-comentario-cadastro-avaliacao">
              <h:inputTextarea class="textAreaComentarioMarketplace" id="comentario" rows="5" cols="60" maxlength="1000" value="#{marketplaceMB.avaliacao.comentario}" />
              <p:watermark for="comentario" value=" Comentar" />
              <components:fieldMessage fieldId="comentario" />
            </div>

            <div class="container-funcionalidades-cadastrar-avaliacao">
              <div class="botoes-funcionalidades-cadastrar-avaliacao">
                <p:commandLink styleClass="btn botao botao-neutro" process="@this" actionListener="#{marketplaceMB.cancelar}" update="@form:visualizarAvaliacoes @form:pnlAvaliacoes">
                  <i class="material-icons">cancel</i><i class="btn-text">Cancelar</i>
                </p:commandLink>

                <p:commandLink styleClass="btn botao botao-principal" process="@form:visualizarAvaliacoes" actionListener="#{marketplaceMB.salvarAvaliacao}" update="@form:visualizarAvaliacoes @form:pnlAvaliacoes">
                  <i class="material-icons">reviews</i><i class="btn-text">Avaliar</i>
                </p:commandLink>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
        [...]
  </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

And my managed bean pass with this two methods:

```
public void limpar() {
        anuncio = null;
        avaliacao = null;
    }

public void novaAvaliacao() {
        limpar();

        avaliacao = new Avaliacao();
    }
```

I believe that the problem is because my panelGroup isn't rendered when I call the function 'dialogScroll', but I don't find a way to loading my function just when the document is fully loaded.

Comment: Please [edit], then click `[<>]` and create a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML. What you posted is not XHTML but PrimeFaces

Comment: If `dialogId` is a string that is the id of some page element, then `$(dialogId)` will not work. You need `$("#" + dialogId)`

Comment: I already introduce the $("#" + dialogId), and my code doesn't work. I was put $("#" + dialogId) and $("#" + elementId)

Comment: @mplungjan: It **is** XHTML. What a lot of people don't know/realize is that XHTML is normally used in order to be able to produce HTML pages using a XML based tool in the server side. People who actually use XHTML as-is in client side have essentially no idea what they're doing and should be using plain HTML5 instead. See also among others https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869174. And moreover, the usage of XHTML is not per definition PrimeFaces-related but JSF-related.

Comment: @BalusC I have used XML and XHTML since it was invented. What is posted may adhere to the XHTML standard but is useless in this question since it is not rendered (X)HTML as understood by a browser and does belong in a [mcve] that needs jQuery solutions.
I should possibly have been clearer in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

If console.log in line 3 returns empty elementID, as I understand, I would just cut `'dialogForm:'` from
`dialogScroll('modalAnuncio', 'dialogForm:panelDialog')"`
since I believe it should be focused on dialogForm already.
I'm 90% sure you are passing unexisting element ID.

I can't really reproduce this particular scenario so take this reply with grain of salt