# Error parsing XHTML: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml, facelets

As an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304132/hcommandbutton-multiple-actions-download-file-and-render-ajax-table), I'm trying to insert Javascript to a `<h:commandButton />`'s `onclick` property as `action` is already rendering an ajax table.

What I want to do:
Get the selected items in a list box and turn them into parameters to be used in a JSF `FileServlet`. i.e. `para2=value1&param=value2&param=value3`

Here's what I have:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function myScript() {
    var box = document.getElementbyId('myForm:box');
    var length = box.options.length;
    var paramstring = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i != (length - 1) {
            if (box.options[i].selected) {
                paramstring = paramstring + "param=" + box.options[i].value + "&amp;";
            }
        } else {
            paramstring = paramstring + "param=" + box.options[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById('myForm:checkbox').checked) {
        window.location='fileServlet? + paramstring;
    }
}
</script>
```

What I get when page is loaded:
`javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line:15] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.`

What doesn't trigger exception:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function myScript() {
    var box = document.getElementbyId('myForm:box');
    var length = box.options.length;
    var paramstring = "";

    if (document.getElementById('myForm:checkbox').checked) {
        window.location='fileServlet? + paramstring;
    }
}
</script>
```

As soon as I add in `for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)` or even `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)` the page wouldn't load. Why does it not like the for loop?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology which uses XHTML+XML to generate HTML output. XML has five special characters which has special treatment by the XML parser:

- `<` the start of a tag.
- `>` the end of a tag.
- `"` the start and end of an attribute value.
- `'` the alternative start and end of an attribute value.
- `&` the start of an entity (which ends with `;`).

In case of `<`, the XML parser is implicitly looking for the tag name and the end tag `>`. However, in your particular case, you were using `<` as a JavaScript operator, not as an XML entity. This totally explains the XML parsing error you got:

> The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

In essence, you're writing JavaScript code in the wrong place, a XML document instead of a JS file, so you should be escaping all XML special characters accordingly. The `<` must be escaped as `&lt;`.

So, essentially, the

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
```

must become

```
for (var i = 0; i &lt; length; i++) {
```

to make it XML-valid.

However, this makes the JavaScript code harder to read and maintain. As stated in Mozilla Developer Network's excellent document [Writing JavaScript for XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Writing_JavaScript_for_HTML), you should be placing the JavaScript code in a character data (CDATA) block. Thus, in JSF terms, that would be:

```
<h:outputScript>
    <![CDATA[
        // ...
    ]]>
</h:outputScript>
```

The XML parser will interpret the block's contents as "plain vanilla" character data and not as XML and hence interpret the XML special characters "as-is".

But, much better is to just put the JS code in its own JS file which you include by `<script src>`, or in JSF terms, the `<h:outputScript>`.

```
<h:outputScript name="functions.js" target="head" />
```

This way you don't need to worry about XML-special characters in your JS code. Additional advantage is that this gives the browser the opportunity to cache the JS file so that average response size is smaller.

#### See also:

- [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference/16328808#16328808)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [Writing JavaScript for XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/Writing_JavaScript_for_HTML)

Comment: The javascript doesn't run when I use the `<![CDATA[` block or using an external js file. I shortened the code for `myScript()` to `window.location='fileServlet?param=1';`, and this only runs if I put it inline with `onclick` or in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: How did you invoke it? By `onclick="myScript()"` I suppose?

Comment: While wrapping in `<![CDATA[` did you ensure that you followed the instructions in the link as in my answer? There has got to be a `]]>` at end. When using an external script, did you ensure that the `.js` file didn't contain the `<script>`, but just a `function myScript() {}` ?

Comment: yes, I used a `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` block and had a `global.js` with only `function myScript() {}`

Comment: I spotted some minor errors in your JS function (among others, you omitted a `'`, but that should have resulted in a JS error, did you see it in JS console?) and the logic could be more simplified. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Dang it, I was typing in the same answer.  Including your javascript in a separate file will definitely solve this issue, and is generally a best practice.

Comment: @Naganalf: You started typing 44 minutes ago? :)

Comment: Started yes, then something came up here to distract me.  :P

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. But again, running it in `global.js` like the example, even if I shorten it to `window.location='fileServlet?param=1';` it doesn't seem to run.

Comment: @Naganalf: Haha ok. Sorry about that :P Next time better.

Comment: It doesn't get invoked at all? Do you see any JS errors in the JS console? Is the `global.js` reachable anyway? (i.e. its URL is correct and so on). Web developer tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) for Firefox may give lot of new insights.

Comment: Ok, after restarting server and refreshing page, clearing browser cache a couple times I got the `global.js` running. But only this part `if(checked) window.location='fileServlet?param=1';` As soon as I put in the line `var box = document.getElementbyId('myForm:box');` it doesn't download the file, even when the param is currently hard-coded. I will look into using Firebug.

Comment: Only by just putting this line? Interesting, this would suggest that calling `document` threw an exception. Anyway, is the element ID correct as per the generated HTML?

Comment: yup, my listbox id is `box` and my form id is `myForm` It was able to get the checkbox element.

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+J` to get the standard JS error console in Firefox. It might contain useful debug information.

Comment: ah I was using `getElementbyId` instead of `getElementById` Now it triggers the download.

Comment: Thanks for tip on using external js and error console and fixing the logic too.

Comment: Ahh, my own typo. Sorry about that. Just typed straight from head :) But is it now working?

Comment: It's only passing one param so far instead of the whole chain. I'm using `getParameterValues`.  I'll get back to you.

Comment: Hmm, I shouldn't be doing `length - 1`, that's the options available in list box not the total of selected. I'll get back to you.

Comment: This should actually not harm. Put an `alert(paramstring)` or with Firebug, `console.log(paramstring)` before `window.location` to see if it's correct.

Comment: but the paramstring before was putting `&amp;` at the end because it wasn't at `length - 1` even when I was already at the end of all the selections. I updated the code now, please see updated question. thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer, but I see that you used `&amp;` in JS. This is unnecessary. The `&amp;` is only necessary when writing in a XML file. The XML parser will then turn it into a `&`.

Comment: Ignore the code that I updated, yours is outputting the correct `paramstring` and I'm getting the correct String array with `getParameterValues`. Thanks.

Comment: I am using left shift operator in my code ( << ) for this it is giving me that  Error parsing XHTML: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Comment: Wow, how in a earth, you have found out this.

Answer (score 22):

I ran across this post today as I was running into the same issue and had the same problem of the javascript not running with the CDATA tags listed above.  I corrected the CDATA tags to look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 

your javascript code here

//]]>
</script>
```

Then everything worked perfectly!

Comment: This means that you're serving HTML as `application/xhtml+xml` (see also the CDATA link in my answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML). Serving HTML as such is considered harmful (especially in MSIE browser).

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you will need this :

```
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 /*]]>*/
```

and not only this :

```
 <![CDATA[
 ]]>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a git conflict left in my workspace.xml 
i.e.

```
<<<<———————HEAD
```

which caused the unknown tag error. It is a bit annoying that it doesn’t name the file.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this converting the JSP from XHTML to HTML, doing this in the begining:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
...
```