# How to handle < and > signs in javascript in .xhtml page?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2 .xhtml page with javascript in the page code.
In that javascript code, I have the folowing:

```
                    var lat1 = latlng1.lat();
                    var lat2 = latlng2.lat();
                    var minLat = lat1<lat2?lat1:lat2;
                    var maxLat = lat1<lat2?lat2:lat1;
```

I get a page error that complains about the < sign - apparently the parser thinks it is an xml type symbol, rather than a "less than" sign.

**javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /index_2.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 87] Element type "lat2" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".**

How can I get around this?

I suspect I can probably move it into a javascript library, but I am just trying to do a simple test to see if I can do what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.servlet.ServletException when combining JSF and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/javax-servlet-servletexception-when-combining-jsf-and-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it in a CDATA-section:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

 var lat1 = latlng1.lat();
 var lat2 = latlng2.lat();
 var minLat = lat1<lat2?lat1:lat2;
 var maxLat = lat1<lat2?lat2:lat1;

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

...otherwise a XML-parser will interpret the < as the start of an element. 
CDATA will not be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this with RSF, and what I came up with is... put the javascript in its own file and use `<script src="scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: This is what I meant by putting it into a library.

Comment: I must've missed that part, sorry.