# JSF is transforming doublequotes " in Javascript to &quot;

Tags: javascript, jsf

I need to add dynamic html elements using Javascript in JSF page.

```
<ui:define name="head">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $().ready(function() {
            $(".avisoAlteracao").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("oldValue", $(this).val());
            });
        });

        function checkIfChange(jItem) {
            return jItem.attr("oldValue") != jItem.val();
        }

        function checkChanges() {
            var changed = false;
            $(".avisoAlteracao").each(function() {
                if (checkIfChange($(this)))
                    changed = true;
            });
            return changed;
        }

        function setChangedLabels() {
            var labels = '&lt;ul style="list-style-type: circle;" &gt;';
            $(".avisoAlteracao").each(function() {
                if (checkIfChange($(this))) {
                    label = $("label[for$='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']");
                    labels += "&lt;li&gt;" + label.text() + $(this).val();
                    labels += " -&gt; ";
                    labels += $(this).attr("oldValue") + "&lt;/li&gt;";
                }
            });
            labels += "&lt;/ul&gt;";
            $("#customMessage").html(labels);
        }

    </script>

</ui:define>
```

Ok its very easy but this is what I get from Google Chrome:

```
function setChangedLabels() {
            var labels = "<ul>&quot;;
            $(&quot;.avisoAlteracao&quot;).each(function() {
                if (checkIfChange($(this))) {
                    label = $(&quot;label[for$='&quot; + $(this).attr('id') + &quot;']&quot;);
                    labels += &quot;<li>&quot; + label.text() + $(this).val();
                    labels += &quot; -&gt; &quot;;
                    labels += +$(this).attr('oldValue') + &quot;</li>&quot;;
                }
            });
            labels += &quot;</ul>&quot;;
            $(&quot;#customMessage&quot;).append(labels);
        }
```

I don't know why it transform my " in `&quot;` If I put `&lt;` and `&gt;` works

how can I handle it?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a semicolon after `"<br />"`. Did you copy and paste wrong?

Comment: That code is exactly like your code? Looks like you misstype the **styleClass**

Comment: No its only a example. I will edit to show my real code

Comment: It would be good if you expose how you're including this script in your page, maybe you need `<script type="text/javascript">` and `/* <![CDATA[ */>`.

Comment: I edit it. I already tried with CDATA but without success too.

Comment: @Luiggi: Facelets would throw a XML parsing exception on invalid usage of `<` and `&`. As OP got it to run beyond XML parsing, it's unlikely that a CDATA would fix it. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/javax-servlet-servletexception-error-parsing-page-xhtml-the-content-of-elemen/

Comment: @BalusC you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Mojarra issue and reported as [issue 2443](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2443) and fixed for 2.1.13. It's [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) already at 2.1.17. Look like it's time to upgrade.

That said, you should prefer putting JS code in `.js` files.