# Smaller operator gives error in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a javascript code in my xhtml file. Here it is:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  /> 
     <script>
            function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
                var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
                var el = radio.form.elements;
                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                        el[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
                radio.checked = true;
            }
        </script>
</h:head>
```

The problem ist, inside the for loop it gives error for "<" operator saying that "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.". I think it sees "<" as an html element i.e. "body, html etc. but i am not sure. How can i fix this?

Thanks

Edit: I now tried this but still an error. Is there a syntax error you see?

```
<script>
            function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
                var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
                var el = radio.form.elements;
                for (var i = 0; i &lt; el.length; i++) {
                    if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                        el[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
                radio.checked = true;
            }
        </script>
```

The error says that:

```
myaccounts.xhtml:5:52 Expected ) but found ;
                for (var i = 0; i &lt; el.length; i++) {
                                                ^

myaccounts.xhtml:5:57 Expected ; but found )
                for (var i = 0; i &lt; el.length; i++) {
                                                     ^
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/javax-servlet-servletexception-error-parsing-page-xhtml-the-content-of-elemen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using **CDATA** for the XML parser not to read the javascript content, your code would be like this:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"  /> 
    <script>
        // <![CDATA[
        function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
            var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
            var el = radio.form.elements;
            for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                    el[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
            radio.checked = true;
        }
        // ]]>
    </script>
</h:head>
```

Comment: that appears to work, no errors for now thanks

Comment: also runs correctly thank you

Answer (score 1):

Facelets is a XML based view technology. The characters `<`, `>`, and `&` are special characters in XML. They needs to be replaced by `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;` respectively.

```
for (var i = 0; i &lt; el.length; i++) {
 // your code
}
```

It is better to wrap the entire JS code in a [`<![CDATA[` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML).

Comment: thanks, i tried it but this time it says:  myaccounts.xhtml:5:52 Expected ) but found ;
                    for (var i = 0; i &lt; el.length; i++) {
                                                    ^

myaccounts.xhtml:5:57 Expected ; but found )
                    for (var i = 0; i &lt; el.length; i++) {
                                                         ^