# window.onload in jsf not working

Tags: javascript, jsf, el

I have to call a javascript function on click and onload of a checkbox. In that javascript function, i have to pass a jsf param. the value of the jsf parameter is evaluated and passed on runtime. Value of myClassDataItem.message is being evaluated correctly for Onclick function but in window.onload, value is not being evaluated. 
Is the syntax correct?

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="firstCheckbox" 
onclick= "showMsg('#{myClassDataItem.message}' );"/>

window.onload =  showMsg('#{myClassDataItem.message}');
```

Comment: Where is your `window.onload` located?

Answer (score 0):

Place the `window.onload` call inside a `<script>`-Block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload =  showMsg('#{myClassDataItem.message}');
</script>
```

and it works. My `echoController` simply returns a string object:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class EchoController implements Serializable {
  public String getEchoString() { return "Echo"; }
}
```

and the following pice of code works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showMsg(msg) { alert(msg); }
  window.onload = showMsg('#{echoController.echoString}');
</script>
```

But as mentioned by BalusC inside his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653562/jsf-components-not-parsed-inside-a-script-block?answertab=votes#tab-top) you should not do this at all.