# How to fix the javascript execution error in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (content.style.maxHeight){
    content.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
  } 
});
}
</script>
```

When I am using this code in blogger this shows:-

**"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 301; columnNumber: 16; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
"**
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJCGh.jpg)

Please help me how to fix this problem

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/error-parsing-xhtml-the-content-of-elements-must-consist-of-well-formed-charact

Answer (score 1):

Even just looking at the syntax coloring that you provided in your image, the `<` is giving you problems in this line, line 301:

`for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {`

The parser is interpreting `<` as the start of a tag, and expects a tag name and an end tag `>`. However, I'm guessing you are trying to use it as the JavaScript "less than" operator.

In that case, escape `<` as `&lt;`.

In otherwords, replace that line with:

`for (i = 0; i &lt; coll.length; i++) {`