# I do not know how to de obfuscate this Javascript I found in my blogger template

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am unable to decrypt this script:

```js
   var _0x89b4=[&quot;\x3C&quot;,&quot;\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74&quot;,&quot;\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68&quot;,&quot;\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66&quot;,&quot;\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E&quot;,&quot;\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79&quot;,&quot;\x66\x65\x65\x64&quot;,&quot;\x24\x74&quot;,&quot;\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65&quot;,&quot;\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74&quot;,&quot;\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79&quot;,&quot;\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x61\x24\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x6E\x61\x69\x6C&quot;,&quot;\x75\x72\x6C&quot;,&quot;\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x2E\x62\x70\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x73\x70\x6F\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x2D\x68\x74\x47\x37\x76\x79\x39\x76\x49\x41\x41\x2F\x54\x70\x30\x4B\x72\x4D\x55\x64\x6F\x57\x49\x2F\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x42\x41\x55\x2F\x65\x37\x58\x6B\x46\x74\x45\x72\x71\x73\x55\x2F\x73\x31\x36\x30\x30\x2F\x67\x72\x65\x79\x2E\x47\x49\x46&quot;,&quot;\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B&quot;,&quot;\x72\x65\x6C&quot;,&quot;\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65&quot;,&quot;\x68\x72\x65\x66&quot;,&quot;\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D&quot;,&quot;\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72&quot;,&quot;\x55\x52\x4C&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x2D\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x20\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x66\x69\x78\x27\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27&quot;,&quot;\x27\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x27\x6E\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x74\x6F\x70\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27&quot;,&quot;\x27\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79\x62\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27&quot;,&quot;\x2F\x73\x37\x32\x2D\x63\x2F&quot;,&quot;\x2F\x77&quot;,&quot;\x2D\x68&quot;,&quot;\x2F&quot;,&quot;\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65&quot;,&quot;\x27\x20\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x72\x65\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x6A\x64\x75\x6C\x78\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27&quot;,&quot;\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x74\x6F\x70\x27\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x63\x72\x69\x64\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x63\x72\x69\x64\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64&quot;,&quot;\x2E\x63\x72\x65\x64\x69\x74\x73\x20\x61&quot;,&quot;\x2E\x63\x72&quot;,&quot;\x77\x77\x77\x2E&quot;,&quot;\x74&quot;,&quot;\x65\x64&quot;,&quot;\x69\x74\x73&quot;,&quot;\x69\x74\x65&quot;,&quot;\x2E\x6D&quot;,&quot;\x6B\x72&quot;,&quot;\x67\x73\x70\x6F&quot;,&quot;\x62\x6F\x64\x79&quot;,&quot;\x61&quot;,&quot;\x61\x74\x74\x72&quot;,&quot;\x66\x69\x6E\x64&quot;,&quot;\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F&quot;,&quot;\x69&quot;,&quot;\x39&quot;,&quot;\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D&quot;,&quot;\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x78\x22\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\u0646\u0631\u062C\u0648\x20\u0645\u0646\x20\u0639\u062F\u0645\x20\u062D\u0630\u0641\x20\u062D\u0642\u0648\u0642\x20\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\u0627\u0631\u062C\u0639\x20\u062D\u0642\u0648\u0642\x20\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x20\u062D\u062A\u0649\x20\u064A\u0639\u0645\u0644\x20\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x2E\x6E\x65\x74\x22\x3E\u062D\u0642\u0648\u0642\x20\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x20\u0645\u062D\u0641\u0648\u0636\u0629\x20\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0629\x20\u0627\u062A\u0642\u0627\u0646\x20\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E&quot;,&quot;\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64&quot;,&quot;\x30&quot;,&quot;\x31\x35\x30\x70\x78\x20\x30\x20\x30\x20\x30&quot;,&quot;\x35\x30\x70\x78&quot;,&quot;\x39\x39\x39\x39&quot;,&quot;\x23\x32\x32\x33\x31\x33\x46&quot;,&quot;\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72&quot;,&quot;\x31\x30\x30\x25&quot;,&quot;\x77\x68\x69\x74\x65&quot;,&quot;\x63\x73\x73&quot;,&quot;\x2E\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x78&quot;,&quot;\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D&quot;,&quot;\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E&quot;,&quot;\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79&quot;];var relnojudul=0;var numpost=6;var numchars=120;var image_hightl=400;var image_widthl=630;var reljudul=new Array();var relurls=new Array();var relcuplikan=new Array();var relgambar=new Array();function saringtags(_0xf9ddxb,_0xf9ddxc){var _0xf9ddxd=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[1]](_0x89b4[0]);for(var _0xf9ddxe=0;_0xf9ddxe&lt;_0xf9ddxd[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxe++){if(_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[4]](_0x89b4[3])!=-1){_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe]=_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[5]](_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[4]](_0x89b4[3])+1,_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[2]]);};};_0xf9ddxd=_0xf9ddxd[_0x89b4[7]](_0x89b4[6]);_0xf9ddxd=_0xf9ddxd[_0x89b4[5]](0,_0xf9ddxc-1);return _0xf9ddxd;};function relpostimgcuplik(_0xf9ddxc){for(var _0xf9ddxd=0;_0xf9ddxd&lt;_0xf9ddxc[_0x89b4[9]][_0x89b4[8]][_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxd++){var _0xf9ddxb=_0xf9ddxc[_0x89b4[9]][_0x89b4[8]][_0xf9ddxd];reljudul[relnojudul]=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[11]][_0x89b4[10]];postcontent=_0x89b4[6];if(_0x89b4[12]in _0xf9ddxb){postcontent=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[12]][_0x89b4[10]];}else{if(_0x89b4[13]in _0xf9ddxb){postcontent=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[13]][_0x89b4[10]];};};relcuplikan[relnojudul]=saringtags(postcontent,numchars);if(_0x89b4[14]in _0xf9ddxb){postimg=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[14]][_0x89b4[15]];}else{postimg=_0x89b4[16];};relgambar[relnojudul]=postimg;for(var _0xf9ddxe=0;_0xf9ddxe&lt;_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[17]][_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxe++){if(_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[17]][_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[18]]==_0x89b4[19]){relurls[relnojudul]=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[17]][_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[20]];break;};};relnojudul++;};};function contains(_0xf9ddx11,_0xf9ddxd){for(var _0xf9ddxe=0;_0xf9ddxe&lt;_0xf9ddx11[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxe++){if(_0xf9ddx11[_0xf9ddxe]==_0xf9ddxd){return true;};};return false;};function artikelterkait(){var _0xf9ddx13=new Array(0);var _0xf9ddx14=new Array(0);var _0xf9ddx15=new Array(0);var _0xf9ddx16=new Array(0);for(var _0xf9ddx17=0;_0xf9ddx17&lt;relurls[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddx17++){if(!contains(_0xf9ddx13,relurls[_0xf9ddx17])){_0xf9ddx13[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx13[_0xf9ddx13[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=relurls[_0xf9ddx17];_0xf9ddx14[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx14[_0xf9ddx14[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=reljudul[_0xf9ddx17];_0xf9ddx15[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx15[_0xf9ddx15[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17];_0xf9ddx16[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx16[_0xf9ddx16[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=relgambar[_0xf9ddx17];};};reljudul=_0xf9ddx14;relurls=_0xf9ddx13;relcuplikan=_0xf9ddx15;relgambar=_0xf9ddx16;for(var _0xf9ddx17=0;_0xf9ddx17&lt;reljudul[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddx17++){var _0xf9ddx18=Math[_0x89b4[22]]((reljudul[_0x89b4[2]]-1)*Math[_0x89b4[21]]());var _0xf9ddx19=reljudul[_0xf9ddx17];var _0xf9ddx1a=relurls[_0xf9ddx17];var _0xf9ddx1b=relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17];var _0xf9ddx1c=relgambar[_0xf9ddx17];reljudul[_0xf9ddx17]=reljudul[_0xf9ddx18];relurls[_0xf9ddx17]=relurls[_0xf9ddx18];relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17]=relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx18];relgambar[_0xf9ddx17]=relgambar[_0xf9ddx18];reljudul[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx19;relurls[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx1a;relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx1b;relgambar[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx1c;};var _0xf9ddx1d=0;var _0xf9ddx1e=Math[_0x89b4[22]]((reljudul[_0x89b4[2]]-1)*Math[_0x89b4[21]]());var _0xf9ddx1f=_0xf9ddx1e;var _0xf9ddx20;var _0xf9ddx21=document[_0x89b4[23]];while(_0xf9ddx1d&lt;numpost){if(relurls[_0xf9ddx1e]!=_0xf9ddx21){_0xf9ddx20=_0x89b4[24];_0xf9ddx20+=_0x89b4[25]+relurls[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[26]+reljudul[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[27]+relgambar[_0xf9ddx1e][_0x89b4[32]](_0x89b4[28],_0x89b4[29]+image_widthl+_0x89b4[30]+image_hightl+_0x89b4[31])+_0x89b4[33];_0xf9ddx20+=_0x89b4[34]+relurls[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[35]+reljudul[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[36];_0xf9ddx20+=_0x89b4[37];document[_0x89b4[38]](_0xf9ddx20);_0xf9ddx1d++;if(_0xf9ddx1d==numpost){break;};};if(_0xf9ddx1e&lt;reljudul[_0x89b4[2]]-1){_0xf9ddx1e++;}else{_0xf9ddx1e=0;};if(_0xf9ddx1e==_0xf9ddx1f){break;};};};$(document)[_0x89b4[73]](function(){$(_0x89b4[41])[_0x89b4[40]](_0x89b4[39]);var _0xf9ddx22=_0x89b4[20],_0xf9ddx1b=_0x89b4[42],_0xf9ddx17=_0x89b4[43],_0xf9ddx1a=_0x89b4[44],_0xf9ddx21=_0x89b4[45],_0xf9ddx15=_0x89b4[46],_0xf9ddx14=_0x89b4[47],_0xf9ddx20=_0x89b4[48],_0xf9ddx23=_0x89b4[49],_0xf9ddx24=_0xf9ddx1b+_0xf9ddx21+_0xf9ddx15,_0xf9ddx13=_0x89b4[50],_0xf9ddx1f=_0x89b4[51],_0xf9ddx1d=_0x89b4[52];if($(_0xf9ddx24)[_0x89b4[54]](_0x89b4[52])[_0x89b4[53]](_0xf9ddx22)==_0x89b4[55]+_0xf9ddx17+_0x89b4[56]+_0xf9ddx1a+_0x89b4[57]+_0xf9ddx1d+_0x89b4[58]){}else{$(_0xf9ddx1f)[_0x89b4[40]](_0x89b4[59]);$(_0x89b4[70])[_0x89b4[69]]({position:_0x89b4[60],top:_0x89b4[61],padding:_0x89b4[62],&quot;\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x73\x69\x7A\x65&quot;:_0x89b4[63],&quot;\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78&quot;:_0x89b4[64],&quot;\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64&quot;:_0x89b4[65],&quot;\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E&quot;:_0x89b4[66],width:_0x89b4[67],height:_0x89b4[67],color:_0x89b4[68]});var _0xf9ddx11=_0x89b4[71];setTimeout(function(){document[_0x89b4[72]]=_0xf9ddx11;},3000);};});window.selectnav=function(){&quot;use strict&quot;;var e=function(e,t){function c(e){var t;if(!e)e=window.event;if(e.target)t=e.target;else if(e.srcElement)t=e.srcElement;if(t.nodeType===3)t=t.parentNode;if(t.value)window.location.href=t.value}function h(e){var t=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return t===&quot;ul&quot;||t===&quot;ol&quot;}function p(e){for(var t=1;document.getElementById(&quot;selectnav&quot;+t);t++);return e?&quot;selectnav&quot;+t:&quot;selectnav&quot;+(t-1)}function d(e){a++;var t=e.children.length,n=&quot;&quot;,l=&quot;&quot;,c=a-1;if(!t){return}if(c){while(c--){l+=o}l+=&quot; &quot;}for(var v=0;v&lt;t;v++){var m=e.children[v].children[0];if(typeof m!==&quot;undefined&quot;){var g=m.innerText||m.textContent;var y=&quot;&quot;;if(r){y=m.className.search(r)!==-1||m.parentNode.className.search(r)!==-1?f:&quot;&quot;}if(i&amp;&amp;!y){y=m.href===document.URL?f:&quot;&quot;}n+=&#39;&lt;option value=&quot;&#39;+m.href+&#39;&quot; &#39;+y+&quot;&gt;&quot;+l+g+&quot;&lt;/option&gt;&quot;;if(s){var b=e.children[v].children[1];if(b&amp;&amp;h(b)){n+=d(b)}}}}if(a===1&amp;&amp;u){n=&#39;&lt;option value=&quot;&quot;&gt;&#39;+u+&quot;&lt;/option&gt;&quot;+n}if(a===1){n=&#39;&lt;select class=&quot;selectnav&quot; id=&quot;&#39;+p(true)+&#39;&quot;&gt;&#39;+n+&quot;&lt;/select&gt;&quot;}a--;return n}e=document.getElementById(e);if(!e){return}if(!h(e)){return}if(!(&quot;insertAdjacentHTML&quot;in window.document.documentElement)){return}document.documentElement.className+=&quot; js&quot;;var n=t||{},r=n.activeclass||&quot;active&quot;,i=typeof n.autoselect===&quot;boolean&quot;?n.autoselect:true,s=typeof n.nested===&quot;boolean&quot;?n.nested:true,o=n.indent||&quot;&#8594;&quot;,u=n.label||&quot;- Navigation -&quot;,a=0,f=&quot; selected &quot;;e.insertAdjacentHTML(&quot;afterend&quot;,d(e));var l=document.getElementById(p());if(l.addEventListener){l.addEventListener(&quot;change&quot;,c)}if(l.attachEvent){l.attachEvent(&quot;onchange&quot;,c)}return l};return function(t,n){e(t,n)}}();(function(a){a.fn.gotop=function(c){var d=a.extend({content:960,bottom:30,margin:&quot;none&quot;,position:&quot;left&quot;,scrollTop:100,duration:700},c);var g=a(window);var f=this;function h(){var i=true;if(d.margin==&quot;none&quot;){if(g.width()&lt;(d.content+(f.width()*2)+4)){i=false}}else{if(g.width()&lt;(d.content+((f.width()+d.right)*2)+4)){i=false}}return i}function b(){var i=(((g.width()-d.content)/2)-f.width())/2;if(d.position==&quot;left&quot;||d.position==&quot;l&quot;){f.css({left:i+&quot;px&quot;})}else{f.css({right:i+&quot;px&quot;})}}function e(){if(g.scrollTop()&gt;d.scrollTop){f.fadeIn()}else{f.fadeOut()}}if(!h()){this.hide()}if(d.margin==&quot;none&quot;){b()}else{if(d.position==&quot;left&quot;||d.position==&quot;l&quot;){f.css({left:d.margin+&quot;px&quot;})}else{f.css({right:d.margin+&quot;px&quot;})}}e();g.resize(function(){if(h()){f.fadeIn()}else{f.fadeOut()}if(d.margin==&quot;none&quot;){b()}});g.scroll(function(){e()});return this.css({position:&quot;fixed&quot;,cursor:&quot;pointer&quot;,bottom:d.bottom+&quot;px&quot;}).click(function(){a(&quot;body,html&quot;).animate({scrollTop:0},d.duration)})}})(jQuery);
```

I attempted to use several services but was stopped by JSCompress, which displayed the following error:

> Unexpected token: operator «&» (line: 1, col: 16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code is not actual valid JavaScript as-is. It has a lot of HTML characters that have been replaced with HTML character codes (similar to being parsed with `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP). This does things like replace `&` with `&amp;` or `'` with `&#39;`, which causes it to fail during deobfuscation.

Simply swapping back all of the special HTML character codes for their actual values allows it to be parsed/deobfuscated.

**Fixed** Code:

```
var _0x89b4=["\x3C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x3E","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79","\x66\x65\x65\x64","\x24\x74","\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65","\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74","\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79","\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x61\x24\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x6E\x61\x69\x6C","\x75\x72\x6C","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x2E\x62\x70\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x73\x70\x6F\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x2D\x68\x74\x47\x37\x76\x79\x39\x76\x49\x41\x41\x2F\x54\x70\x30\x4B\x72\x4D\x55\x64\x6F\x57\x49\x2F\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x42\x41\x55\x2F\x65\x37\x58\x6B\x46\x74\x45\x72\x71\x73\x55\x2F\x73\x31\x36\x30\x30\x2F\x67\x72\x65\x79\x2E\x47\x49\x46","\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B","\x72\x65\x6C","\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D","\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72","\x55\x52\x4C","\x3C\x6C\x69\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x6E\x65\x77\x73\x2D\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x20\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x66\x69\x78\x27\x3E","\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27","\x27\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x27\x6E\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x74\x6F\x70\x27\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x27","\x27\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79\x62\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27","\x2F\x73\x37\x32\x2D\x63\x2F","\x2F\x77","\x2D\x68","\x2F","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x27\x20\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x27\x72\x65\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x6A\x64\x75\x6C\x78\x27\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x27","\x27\x20\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x3D\x27\x5F\x74\x6F\x70\x27\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65","\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x63\x72\x69\x64\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x63\x72\x69\x64\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64","\x2E\x63\x72\x65\x64\x69\x74\x73\x20\x61","\x2E\x63\x72","\x77\x77\x77\x2E","\x74","\x65\x64","\x69\x74\x73","\x69\x74\x65","\x2E\x6D","\x6B\x72","\x67\x73\x70\x6F","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x61","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x66\x69\x6E\x64","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F","\x69","\x39","\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x78\x22\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\u0646\u0631\u062C\u0648\x20\u0645\u0646\x20\u0639\u062F\u0645\x20\u062D\u0630\u0641\x20\u062D\u0642\u0648\u0642\x20\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\u0627\u0631\u062C\u0639\x20\u062D\u0642\u0648\u0642\x20\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x20\u062D\u062A\u0649\x20\u064A\u0639\u0645\u0644\x20\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x2E\x6E\x65\x74\x22\x3E\u062D\u0642\u0648\u0642\x20\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x20\u0645\u062D\u0641\u0648\u0636\u0629\x20\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0629\x20\u0627\u062A\u0642\u0627\u0646\x20\u0644\u062A\u0635\u0645\u064A\u0645\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x66\x69\x78\x65\x64","\x30","\x31\x35\x30\x70\x78\x20\x30\x20\x30\x20\x30","\x35\x30\x70\x78","\x39\x39\x39\x39","\x23\x32\x32\x33\x31\x33\x46","\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72","\x31\x30\x30\x25","\x77\x68\x69\x74\x65","\x63\x73\x73","\x2E\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x78","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x69\x74\x39\x61\x6E\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"];var relnojudul=0;var numpost=6;var numchars=120;var image_hightl=400;var image_widthl=630;var reljudul=new Array();var relurls=new Array();var relcuplikan=new Array();var relgambar=new Array();function saringtags(_0xf9ddxb,_0xf9ddxc){var _0xf9ddxd=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[1]](_0x89b4[0]);for(var _0xf9ddxe=0;_0xf9ddxe<_0xf9ddxd[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxe++){if(_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[4]](_0x89b4[3])!=-1){_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe]=_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[5]](_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[4]](_0x89b4[3])+1,_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[2]]);};};_0xf9ddxd=_0xf9ddxd[_0x89b4[7]](_0x89b4[6]);_0xf9ddxd=_0xf9ddxd[_0x89b4[5]](0,_0xf9ddxc-1);return _0xf9ddxd;};function relpostimgcuplik(_0xf9ddxc){for(var _0xf9ddxd=0;_0xf9ddxd<_0xf9ddxc[_0x89b4[9]][_0x89b4[8]][_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxd++){var _0xf9ddxb=_0xf9ddxc[_0x89b4[9]][_0x89b4[8]][_0xf9ddxd];reljudul[relnojudul]=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[11]][_0x89b4[10]];postcontent=_0x89b4[6];if(_0x89b4[12]in _0xf9ddxb){postcontent=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[12]][_0x89b4[10]];}else{if(_0x89b4[13]in _0xf9ddxb){postcontent=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[13]][_0x89b4[10]];};};relcuplikan[relnojudul]=saringtags(postcontent,numchars);if(_0x89b4[14]in _0xf9ddxb){postimg=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[14]][_0x89b4[15]];}else{postimg=_0x89b4[16];};relgambar[relnojudul]=postimg;for(var _0xf9ddxe=0;_0xf9ddxe<_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[17]][_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxe++){if(_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[17]][_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[18]]==_0x89b4[19]){relurls[relnojudul]=_0xf9ddxb[_0x89b4[17]][_0xf9ddxe][_0x89b4[20]];break;};};relnojudul++;};};function contains(_0xf9ddx11,_0xf9ddxd){for(var _0xf9ddxe=0;_0xf9ddxe<_0xf9ddx11[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddxe++){if(_0xf9ddx11[_0xf9ddxe]==_0xf9ddxd){return true;};};return false;};function artikelterkait(){var _0xf9ddx13=new Array(0);var _0xf9ddx14=new Array(0);var _0xf9ddx15=new Array(0);var _0xf9ddx16=new Array(0);for(var _0xf9ddx17=0;_0xf9ddx17<relurls[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddx17++){if(!contains(_0xf9ddx13,relurls[_0xf9ddx17])){_0xf9ddx13[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx13[_0xf9ddx13[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=relurls[_0xf9ddx17];_0xf9ddx14[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx14[_0xf9ddx14[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=reljudul[_0xf9ddx17];_0xf9ddx15[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx15[_0xf9ddx15[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17];_0xf9ddx16[_0x89b4[2]]+=1;_0xf9ddx16[_0xf9ddx16[_0x89b4[2]]-1]=relgambar[_0xf9ddx17];};};reljudul=_0xf9ddx14;relurls=_0xf9ddx13;relcuplikan=_0xf9ddx15;relgambar=_0xf9ddx16;for(var _0xf9ddx17=0;_0xf9ddx17<reljudul[_0x89b4[2]];_0xf9ddx17++){var _0xf9ddx18=Math[_0x89b4[22]]((reljudul[_0x89b4[2]]-1)*Math[_0x89b4[21]]());var _0xf9ddx19=reljudul[_0xf9ddx17];var _0xf9ddx1a=relurls[_0xf9ddx17];var _0xf9ddx1b=relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17];var _0xf9ddx1c=relgambar[_0xf9ddx17];reljudul[_0xf9ddx17]=reljudul[_0xf9ddx18];relurls[_0xf9ddx17]=relurls[_0xf9ddx18];relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17]=relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx18];relgambar[_0xf9ddx17]=relgambar[_0xf9ddx18];reljudul[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx19;relurls[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx1a;relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx1b;relgambar[_0xf9ddx18]=_0xf9ddx1c;};var _0xf9ddx1d=0;var _0xf9ddx1e=Math[_0x89b4[22]]((reljudul[_0x89b4[2]]-1)*Math[_0x89b4[21]]());var _0xf9ddx1f=_0xf9ddx1e;var _0xf9ddx20;var _0xf9ddx21=document[_0x89b4[23]];while(_0xf9ddx1d<numpost){if(relurls[_0xf9ddx1e]!=_0xf9ddx21){_0xf9ddx20=_0x89b4[24];_0xf9ddx20+=_0x89b4[25]+relurls[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[26]+reljudul[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[27]+relgambar[_0xf9ddx1e][_0x89b4[32]](_0x89b4[28],_0x89b4[29]+image_widthl+_0x89b4[30]+image_hightl+_0x89b4[31])+_0x89b4[33];_0xf9ddx20+=_0x89b4[34]+relurls[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[35]+reljudul[_0xf9ddx1e]+_0x89b4[36];_0xf9ddx20+=_0x89b4[37];document[_0x89b4[38]](_0xf9ddx20);_0xf9ddx1d++;if(_0xf9ddx1d==numpost){break;};};if(_0xf9ddx1e<reljudul[_0x89b4[2]]-1){_0xf9ddx1e++;}else{_0xf9ddx1e=0;};if(_0xf9ddx1e==_0xf9ddx1f){break;};};};$(document)[_0x89b4[73]](function(){$(_0x89b4[41])[_0x89b4[40]](_0x89b4[39]);var _0xf9ddx22=_0x89b4[20],_0xf9ddx1b=_0x89b4[42],_0xf9ddx17=_0x89b4[43],_0xf9ddx1a=_0x89b4[44],_0xf9ddx21=_0x89b4[45],_0xf9ddx15=_0x89b4[46],_0xf9ddx14=_0x89b4[47],_0xf9ddx20=_0x89b4[48],_0xf9ddx23=_0x89b4[49],_0xf9ddx24=_0xf9ddx1b+_0xf9ddx21+_0xf9ddx15,_0xf9ddx13=_0x89b4[50],_0xf9ddx1f=_0x89b4[51],_0xf9ddx1d=_0x89b4[52];if($(_0xf9ddx24)[_0x89b4[54]](_0x89b4[52])[_0x89b4[53]](_0xf9ddx22)==_0x89b4[55]+_0xf9ddx17+_0x89b4[56]+_0xf9ddx1a+_0x89b4[57]+_0xf9ddx1d+_0x89b4[58]){}else{$(_0xf9ddx1f)[_0x89b4[40]](_0x89b4[59]);$(_0x89b4[70])[_0x89b4[69]]({position:_0x89b4[60],top:_0x89b4[61],padding:_0x89b4[62],"\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x2D\x73\x69\x7A\x65":_0x89b4[63],"\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78":_0x89b4[64],"\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x67\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64":_0x89b4[65],"\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2D\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E":_0x89b4[66],width:_0x89b4[67],height:_0x89b4[67],color:_0x89b4[68]});var _0xf9ddx11=_0x89b4[71];setTimeout(function(){document[_0x89b4[72]]=_0xf9ddx11;},3000);};});window.selectnav=function(){"use strict";var e=function(e,t){function c(e){var t;if(!e)e=window.event;if(e.target)t=e.target;else if(e.srcElement)t=e.srcElement;if(t.nodeType===3)t=t.parentNode;if(t.value)window.location.href=t.value}function h(e){var t=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return t==="ul"||t==="ol"}function p(e){for(var t=1;document.getElementById("selectnav"+t);t++);return e?"selectnav"+t:"selectnav"+(t-1)}function d(e){a++;var t=e.children.length,n="",l="",c=a-1;if(!t){return}if(c){while(c--){l+=o}l+=" "}for(var v=0;v<t;v++){var m=e.children[v].children[0];if(typeof m!=="undefined"){var g=m.innerText||m.textContent;var y="";if(r){y=m.className.search(r)!==-1||m.parentNode.className.search(r)!==-1?f:""}if(i&&!y){y=m.href===document.URL?f:""}n+='<option value="'+m.href+'" '+y+">"+l+g+"</option>";if(s){var b=e.children[v].children[1];if(b&&h(b)){n+=d(b)}}}}if(a===1&&u){n='<option value="">'+u+"</option>"+n}if(a===1){n='<select class="selectnav" id="'+p(true)+'">'+n+"</select>"}a--;return n}e=document.getElementById(e);if(!e){return}if(!h(e)){return}if(!("insertAdjacentHTML"in window.document.documentElement)){return}document.documentElement.className+=" js";var n=t||{},r=n.activeclass||"active",i=typeof n.autoselect==="boolean"?n.autoselect:true,s=typeof n.nested==="boolean"?n.nested:true,o=n.indent||"&#8594;",u=n.label||"- Navigation -",a=0,f=" selected ";e.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",d(e));var l=document.getElementById(p());if(l.addEventListener){l.addEventListener("change",c)}if(l.attachEvent){l.attachEvent("onchange",c)}return l};return function(t,n){e(t,n)}}();(function(a){a.fn.gotop=function(c){var d=a.extend({content:960,bottom:30,margin:"none",position:"left",scrollTop:100,duration:700},c);var g=a(window);var f=this;function h(){var i=true;if(d.margin=="none"){if(g.width()<(d.content+(f.width()*2)+4)){i=false}}else{if(g.width()<(d.content+((f.width()+d.right)*2)+4)){i=false}}return i}function b(){var i=(((g.width()-d.content)/2)-f.width())/2;if(d.position=="left"||d.position=="l"){f.css({left:i+"px"})}else{f.css({right:i+"px"})}}function e(){if(g.scrollTop()>d.scrollTop){f.fadeIn()}else{f.fadeOut()}}if(!h()){this.hide()}if(d.margin=="none"){b()}else{if(d.position=="left"||d.position=="l"){f.css({left:d.margin+"px"})}else{f.css({right:d.margin+"px"})}}e();g.resize(function(){if(h()){f.fadeIn()}else{f.fadeOut()}if(d.margin=="none"){b()}});g.scroll(function(){e()});return this.css({position:"fixed",cursor:"pointer",bottom:d.bottom+"px"}).click(function(){a("body,html").animate({scrollTop:0},d.duration)})}})(jQuery);
```

**Deobfuscated** Code:

```js
var relnojudul = 0;
var numpost = 6;
var numchars = 120;
var image_hightl = 400;
var image_widthl = 630;
var reljudul = new Array;
var relurls = new Array;
var relcuplikan = new Array;
var relgambar = new Array;
function saringtags(_0xf9ddxb, _0xf9ddxc) {
  var _0xf9ddxd = _0xf9ddxb.split("<");
  for (var _0xf9ddxe = 0; _0xf9ddxe < _0xf9ddxd.length; _0xf9ddxe++) {
    if (_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe].indexOf(">") != -1) {
      _0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe] = _0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe].substring(_0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe].indexOf(">") + 1, _0xf9ddxd[_0xf9ddxe].length);
    }
    ;
  }
  ;
  _0xf9ddxd = _0xf9ddxd.join("");
  _0xf9ddxd = _0xf9ddxd.substring(0, _0xf9ddxc - 1);
  return _0xf9ddxd;
}
;
function relpostimgcuplik(_0xf9ddxc) {
  for (var _0xf9ddxd = 0; _0xf9ddxd < _0xf9ddxc.feed.entry.length; _0xf9ddxd++) {
    var _0xf9ddxb = _0xf9ddxc.feed.entry[_0xf9ddxd];
    reljudul[relnojudul] = _0xf9ddxb.title.$t;
    postcontent = "";
    if ("content" in _0xf9ddxb) {
      postcontent = _0xf9ddxb.content.$t;
    } else {
      if ("summary" in _0xf9ddxb) {
        postcontent = _0xf9ddxb.summary.$t;
      }
      ;
    }
    ;
    relcuplikan[relnojudul] = saringtags(postcontent, numchars);
    if ("media$thumbnail" in _0xf9ddxb) {
      postimg = _0xf9ddxb.media$thumbnail.url;
    } else {
      postimg = "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-htG7vy9vIAA/Tp0KrMUdoWI/AAAAAAAABAU/e7XkFtErqsU/s1600/grey.GIF";
    }
    ;
    relgambar[relnojudul] = postimg;
    for (var _0xf9ddxe = 0; _0xf9ddxe < _0xf9ddxb.link.length; _0xf9ddxe++) {
      if (_0xf9ddxb.link[_0xf9ddxe].rel == "alternate") {
        relurls[relnojudul] = _0xf9ddxb.link[_0xf9ddxe].href;
        break;
      }
      ;
    }
    ;
    relnojudul++;
  }
  ;
}
;
function contains(_0xf9ddx11, _0xf9ddxd) {
  for (var _0xf9ddxe = 0; _0xf9ddxe < _0xf9ddx11.length; _0xf9ddxe++) {
    if (_0xf9ddx11[_0xf9ddxe] == _0xf9ddxd) {
      return true;
    }
    ;
  }
  ;
  return false;
}
;
function artikelterkait() {
  var _0xf9ddx13 = new Array(0);
  var _0xf9ddx14 = new Array(0);
  var _0xf9ddx15 = new Array(0);
  var _0xf9ddx16 = new Array(0);
  for (var _0xf9ddx17 = 0; _0xf9ddx17 < relurls.length; _0xf9ddx17++) {
    if (!contains(_0xf9ddx13, relurls[_0xf9ddx17])) {
      _0xf9ddx13.length += 1;
      _0xf9ddx13[_0xf9ddx13.length - 1] = relurls[_0xf9ddx17];
      _0xf9ddx14.length += 1;
      _0xf9ddx14[_0xf9ddx14.length - 1] = reljudul[_0xf9ddx17];
      _0xf9ddx15.length += 1;
      _0xf9ddx15[_0xf9ddx15.length - 1] = relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17];
      _0xf9ddx16.length += 1;
      _0xf9ddx16[_0xf9ddx16.length - 1] = relgambar[_0xf9ddx17];
    }
    ;
  }
  ;
  reljudul = _0xf9ddx14;
  relurls = _0xf9ddx13;
  relcuplikan = _0xf9ddx15;
  relgambar = _0xf9ddx16;
  for (var _0xf9ddx17 = 0; _0xf9ddx17 < reljudul.length; _0xf9ddx17++) {
    var _0xf9ddx18 = Math.floor((reljudul.length - 1) * Math.random());
    var _0xf9ddx19 = reljudul[_0xf9ddx17];
    var _0xf9ddx1a = relurls[_0xf9ddx17];
    var _0xf9ddx1b = relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17];
    var _0xf9ddx1c = relgambar[_0xf9ddx17];
    reljudul[_0xf9ddx17] = reljudul[_0xf9ddx18];
    relurls[_0xf9ddx17] = relurls[_0xf9ddx18];
    relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx17] = relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx18];
    relgambar[_0xf9ddx17] = relgambar[_0xf9ddx18];
    reljudul[_0xf9ddx18] = _0xf9ddx19;
    relurls[_0xf9ddx18] = _0xf9ddx1a;
    relcuplikan[_0xf9ddx18] = _0xf9ddx1b;
    relgambar[_0xf9ddx18] = _0xf9ddx1c;
  }
  ;
  var _0xf9ddx1d = 0;
  var _0xf9ddx1e = Math.floor((reljudul.length - 1) * Math.random());
  var _0xf9ddx1f = _0xf9ddx1e;
  var _0xf9ddx20;
  var _0xf9ddx21 = document.URL;
  while (_0xf9ddx1d < numpost) {
    if (relurls[_0xf9ddx1e] != _0xf9ddx21) {
      _0xf9ddx20 = "<li class='news-title clearfix'>";
      _0xf9ddx20 += "<a href='" + relurls[_0xf9ddx1e] + "' rel='nofollow' target='_top' title='" + reljudul[_0xf9ddx1e] + "'><div class='overlayb'><img src='" + relgambar[_0xf9ddx1e].replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + image_widthl + "-h" + image_hightl + "/") + "' /></div></a>";
      _0xf9ddx20 += "<a class='relinkjdulx' href='" + relurls[_0xf9ddx1e] + "' target='_top'>" + reljudul[_0xf9ddx1e] + "</a>";
      _0xf9ddx20 += "</li>";
      document.write(_0xf9ddx20);
      _0xf9ddx1d++;
      if (_0xf9ddx1d == numpost) {
        break;
      }
      ;
    }
    ;
    if (_0xf9ddx1e < reljudul.length - 1) {
      _0xf9ddx1e++;
    } else {
      _0xf9ddx1e = 0;
    }
    ;
    if (_0xf9ddx1e == _0xf9ddx1f) {
      break;
    }
    ;
  }
  ;
}
;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".credits a").append('<span class="it9ancridicon"></span><span class="it9ancridname"></span>');
  var _0xf9ddx22 = "href", _0xf9ddx1b = ".cr", _0xf9ddx17 = "www.", _0xf9ddx1a = "t", _0xf9ddx21 = "ed", _0xf9ddx15 = "its", _0xf9ddx14 = "ite", _0xf9ddx20 = ".m", _0xf9ddx23 = "kr", _0xf9ddx24 = _0xf9ddx1b + _0xf9ddx21 + _0xf9ddx15, _0xf9ddx13 = "gspo", _0xf9ddx1f = "body", _0xf9ddx1d = "a";
  if ($(_0xf9ddx24).find("a").attr(_0xf9ddx22) == "http://" + _0xf9ddx17 + "i" + _0xf9ddx1a + "9" + _0xf9ddx1d + "n.com") {} else {
    $(_0xf9ddx1f).append('<div class="errorx"><p>نرجو من عدم حذف حقوق التصميم</p><p>ارجع حقوق التصميم حتى يعمل الموقع</p><p><a href="http://www.it9an.net">حقوق التصميم محفوضة لشركة اتقان لتصميم</a></p></div>');
    $(".errorx").css({position: "fixed", top: "0", padding: "150px 0 0 0", "font-size": "50px", "z-index": "9999", background: "#22313F", "text-align": "center", width: "100%", height: "100%", color: "white"});
    var _0xf9ddx11 = "http://www.it9an.com";
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.location = _0xf9ddx11;
    }, 3e3);
  }
  ;
});
window.selectnav = function () {
  "use strict";
  var e = function (e, t) {
    function c(e) {
      var t;
      if (!e) e = window.event;
      if (e.target) t = e.target; else if (e.srcElement) t = e.srcElement;
      if (t.nodeType === 3) t = t.parentNode;
      if (t.value) window.location.href = t.value;
    }
    function h(e) {
      var t = e.nodeName.toLowerCase();
      return t === "ul" || t === "ol";
    }
    function p(e) {
      for (var t = 1; document.getElementById("selectnav" + t); t++) ;
      return e ? "selectnav" + t : "selectnav" + (t - 1);
    }
    function d(e) {
      a++;
      var t = e.children.length, n = "", l = "", c = a - 1;
      if (!t) {
        return;
      }
      if (c) {
        while (c--) {
          l += o;
        }
        l += " ";
      }
      for (var v = 0; v < t; v++) {
        var m = e.children[v].children[0];
        if (typeof m !== "undefined") {
          var g = m.innerText || m.textContent;
          var y = "";
          if (r) {
            y = m.className.search(r) !== -1 || m.parentNode.className.search(r) !== -1 ? f : "";
          }
          if (i && !y) {
            y = m.href === document.URL ? f : "";
          }
          n += '<option value="' + m.href + '" ' + y + ">" + l + g + "</option>";
          if (s) {
            var b = e.children[v].children[1];
            if (b && h(b)) {
              n += d(b);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (a === 1 && u) {
        n = '<option value="">' + u + "</option>" + n;
      }
      if (a === 1) {
        n = '<select class="selectnav" id="' + p(true) + '">' + n + "</select>";
      }
      a--;
      return n;
    }
    e = document.getElementById(e);
    if (!e) {
      return;
    }
    if (!h(e)) {
      return;
    }
    if (!("insertAdjacentHTML" in window.document.documentElement)) {
      return;
    }
    document.documentElement.className += " js";
    var n = t || {}, r = n.activeclass || "active", i = typeof n.autoselect === "boolean" ? n.autoselect : true, s = typeof n.nested === "boolean" ? n.nested : true, o = n.indent || "&#8594;", u = n.label || "- Navigation -", a = 0, f = " selected ";
    e.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", d(e));
    var l = document.getElementById(p());
    if (l.addEventListener) {
      l.addEventListener("change", c);
    }
    if (l.attachEvent) {
      l.attachEvent("onchange", c);
    }
    return l;
  };
  return function (t, n) {
    e(t, n);
  };
}();
(function (a) {
  a.fn.gotop = function (c) {
    var d = a.extend({content: 960, bottom: 30, margin: "none", position: "left", scrollTop: 100, duration: 700}, c);
    var g = a(window);
    var f = this;
    function h() {
      var i = true;
      if (d.margin == "none") {
        if (g.width() < d.content + f.width() * 2 + 4) {
          i = false;
        }
      } else {
        if (g.width() < d.content + (f.width() + d.right) * 2 + 4) {
          i = false;
        }
      }
      return i;
    }
    function b() {
      var i = ((g.width() - d.content) / 2 - f.width()) / 2;
      if (d.position == "left" || d.position == "l") {
        f.css({left: i + "px"});
      } else {
        f.css({right: i + "px"});
      }
    }
    function e() {
      if (g.scrollTop() > d.scrollTop) {
        f.fadeIn();
      } else {
        f.fadeOut();
      }
    }
    if (!h()) {
      this.hide();
    }
    if (d.margin == "none") {
      b();
    } else {
      if (d.position == "left" || d.position == "l") {
        f.css({left: d.margin + "px"});
      } else {
        f.css({right: d.margin + "px"});
      }
    }
    e();
    g.resize(function () {
      if (h()) {
        f.fadeIn();
      } else {
        f.fadeOut();
      }
      if (d.margin == "none") {
        b();
      }
    });
    g.scroll(function () {
      e();
    });
    return this.css({position: "fixed", cursor: "pointer", bottom: d.bottom + "px"}).click(function () {
      a("body,html").animate({scrollTop: 0}, d.duration);
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

### UPDATE

Following up on an error commented by OP, it seems there is some sort of special parser for this JavaScript on the server (a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/error-parsing-xhtml-the-content-of-elements-must-consist-of-well-formed-charact) it seems). So in order to upload any updates, the code needs to have those special characters encoded again.

Below is a version that has been re-encoded (linked on CodePen due to character limit):

[Encoded And Deobfuscasted](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/zYjLOOZ)

Comment: Now the fun part begins, figuring out what it does!

Comment: @phuzi It a backlink enforcing redirect script. It limits some editing about copyright this way and oppress my template with dead websites.

Comment: Strange how It was working even though It is not a standard Javascript!

Comment: It shows me this error after I replaced the script in my blogger template:
`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 46; columnNumber: 37; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.` therefore It does want to be saved.

Comment: In fact, I want to remove that redirection script and there is another encrypted script here in my blogger template. I am not that advanced in Javascript even though I made a lot of effort to enhance the original template. [link](https://justpaste.it/76nml)

Comment: @MohammedMehdiTBER From what I can find online, that error message is an issue with how the file is being parsed and certain special characters. Interestingly enough, the special characters all seem to be ones that were encoded before (like `&` and `'`). So the reason it wasn't standard JavaScript to begin with is because whatever is parsing the file needs it to be that way.

Comment: @EssXTee This seems like a professional JavaScript developer, as they didn't just encrypt the script, but made it harder to put it back even after being decrypted.
Do you think that there is a solution to remove the redirect function without removing essential functions? Additionally, even though the malicious function of redirection appeared, I still see some special characters in the decrypted one.