# XHTML version recommended according to w3.org

Tags: xhtml

What is the recommended xhtml version to use these days according with w3.org?

I don´t know but it seems the last recommendation is xhtml 1.1.

But not sure.

Comment: XHTML brings more problems than benefits to most people. Stick to HTML unless you have a really good reason to use XML.

Comment: Related commentary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557827/whats-the-need-for-xhtml/3194601#3194601 If you aren't using any XML tool to procude HTML code, then you're basically going completely offboard when declaring XHTML anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of XHTML to reach Recommendation status is 1.1.

HTML 5 has an XML serialisation and is at Candidate Recommendation status.

Comment: XML serialisation means it´s somewhat like xhtml rules?